# PHP PDO class construction

Tags: php, class, pdo

I'm pretty new to both PDO and OOP.  I'm trying to write a class that connects to a database and updates inserts and modifies it. I have several questions:

1. Is it good practices to connect to the database in the constructor?
2. Should the one class be updating, inserting, modifying and connecting or should it be split up into several classes?
3. Why is runQuery not working? I assume its because $pdo is defined in a different scope. How would I get this working?
4. If the class is include at the top of every page does that mean it will reconnect to the database every time a new page is loaded and will that cause security issues?

Apologies for the overload of questions. Thanks in advance for any answers.

```
<?php
class Login{

private $_username;
private $_password;
private $_host;
private $_database;
private $_driver;

//Connect to the database

function __construct($configFile){

    $connectionDetails = parse_ini_file($configFile);

    $this->_username = $connectionDetails['username'];
    $this->_password = $connectionDetails['password'];
    $this->_host = $connectionDetails['host'];
    $this->_database = $connectionDetails['database'];
    $this->_driver = $connectionDetails['driver'];

    $pdo = new PDO("$this->_driver:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_database", $this->_username, $this->_password);

}

public function loginAllowed($user, $pw){

    $sth = $pdo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($sth);
}

public function runQuery($query, $params){
    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($params); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `$pdo` is a local variable in your constructor and your method `loginAllowed`. You should make it an instance variable (`private $pdo`) so you can call it through `$this->pdo`. I also suggest to use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) here, give the `PDO` class as a parameter in the constructor.

Example

```
<?php
class Login {
    private $pdo;
    // Your other instance variables

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    // Your other methods
}

$pdo = new PDO("...");
$login = new Login($pdo);
```

You shouldn't bother your class with reading settings and initialising your database connection (definitely read about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)), keep it out of your class. Just give the PDO object as a parameter (I used [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), that way you are forced to provide an object of the `PDO` type). Another advantage is that you can now make sure you have only one active database connection (you can manage this in your code base), creating multiple connections is unnecessary and definitely unwanted (performance wise).

Also use [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to include your class definition. Otherwise you will get many errors about redeclaring (and you'd want to avoid that).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer im put all of your suggestions into practice. I'm having a slight issue with the type hinting (without it it works fine) when I pass the $pdo object I get the following error: 

_Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Login::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, string given_

I have used gettype to ensure the variable im passing is in fact a object.  I am baffled.....

Comment: You are giving a string as parameter. What you have to do is create a PDO instance outside of your class, and give this instance as the parameter. (Type hinting is very strong, because you are now able to enforce parameters to be of a type (classes only at this moment).)

Comment: I do this `$pdo = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);` (outside the class) then this `$login = new Login($pdo);` and when i try and print the variable I'm passing ($pdo) I get this: _Object of class PDO could not be converted to string_

Comment: That's strange, for me it works. Can you put a little bit more code on pastebin and post it here? Otherwise it is hard to see what the problem might be.

Comment: I cleaned your code a bit to this: http://pastebin.com/XMUD0Ki6 . If you run this script, what error do you exactly get? (The output you get.)

Comment: Initially I got  _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_VARIABLE_ but I fixed that by adding the $e `catch(PDOException $e)` once that was fixed i got the same error again _Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Login::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, string given_ p.s. your code looks super neat.

Comment: Ow right, you have to give an Exception variable in PHP. I can't run the code at this very time, since I don't have PHP installed on my company computer, so I can't test it. The strange this is, that "$pdo" has a string, rather than an object. Can you tell me what the output is of "var_dump($pdo);"? (If it is too long, use pastebin.)

Comment: In that case, it is strange. I will test it myself later today, when I have access to a PHP environment.

Comment: This code http://pastebin.com/4pUQHMqQ (just that error fixed) seems to be working fine on my host. Did you turn on all error reporting? Which PHP version, webserver do you have? Have you enabled the MySQL (if that is your database) driver for PHP? Are you sure the DSN is all right?

Comment: I am using wamp server, all error reporting is on by default I believe. PHP version: 5.3.9, MySQL is enabled, I have connected to the same database using the MySQL syntax no problems.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my host, using PHP 5.3.6, I cannot tell you what the problem is. The code runs as it should. Are you sure there are no errors at all? From here on, just try to debug etc, just to make sure you didn't miss anything (also copy paste the latest code 1-on-1 and run it). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the db wherever you find it most convenient. Just try to make sure there's only ONE connection. More connections to the same db is a waste of time and resources.
2. The class you refer to is called a model in the MVC architecture. It usually does all the operations on a given table. I see nothing wrong in using a single class for all your needs - as long as the code is readable and maintainable.
3. It's not working because `$pdo` is a local variable. In the ctor, instantiate `$this->pdo` instead.
4. Including a class is not equivalent to instantiating it. A new instance will make another connection. Including it multiple times will only give you a multiple declaration error :). Use `require_once` instead. If you wish to use the instance in multiple files, I strongly suggest you do a quick search regarding the Singleton pattern. Using a singleton object will ensure you always have only one instance of your model object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with all the random stuff, just replacethis in your construct:

```
$pdo = new PDO("$this->_driver:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_database", $this->_username, $this->_password);
```

with

```
$this->pdo = new PDO("$this->_driver:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_database", $this->_username, $this->_password);
```

and reference it as $this->pdo from now on. As simple as that!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it good practices to connect to the database in the constructor?

No good.just connect befor query

```
if($this->pdo == null) {
$this->pdo = new PDO("....");
```

}

2) Should the one class be updating, inserting, modifying and connecting or should it be split up into several classes?
Add methods for class

3) Why is runQuery not working? I assume its because $pdo is defined in a different scope. How would I get this working?
use $this->pdo instead

4) If the class is include at the top of every page does that mean it will reconnect to the database every time a new page is loaded and will that cause security issues?
use static $pdo
then self::$pdo would be the only one connector

```
if(self::$pdo == null) {
self::$pdo = new PDO("....");
```

}